# ARE TEACHING vs TEACH

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context

Please let me know what the difference in meaning is between the following sentences:

1. The tips will save your life if YOU ARE TEACHING English to complete beginners.
2. The tips will save you life if YOU TEACH English to complete beginners.

Comment: There's really no difference. Personally, I'd be more likely to use the first to mean *teaching as a responsibility* and the second to mean *if, for some other reason, you find yourself teaching someone.*

Comment: @Davo Thank you for your reply. How about the following sentences: 1) Ears sweep a liquid in your inner ears when YOU ARE MOVING 2) Ears sweep a liquid in your inner ear when YOU MOVE.

Comment: #2 could be said to, for example, ***trainee*** teachers, since it's much easier to assume a non-explicitly-specified *[if] **at some point in the future** [you teach]*. The continuous version #1 more naturally carries the unspoken implication *if you are [**currently**] teaching*. But in many contexts the intended meaning will be equivalent (and it could in principle be expressed using ***either*** of those meanings, with either verb form). But as a general principle, KISS (use simpler tenses by default).